# Couchbase storing of complex times not firing

Tags: complextype, couchbase

I'm using Couchbase 1.8 to store a collection of complex entities in cache.

Pretty simple scenario, all within a single Console application seems to work find. But when I refactor the same "idea" into a different assembly, nothing seems to work.

The console application:

```
[Serializable]
public class Entity : EntityBase<Entity>
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Entity() { }
}

public abstract class EntityBase<T> : IEntity<T> where T : new()
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<T> Get() { return null; }
}

public interface IEntity<T> where T : new()
{
    Name { get; }
    List<T> Get();
}
```

then in the Console app, I test this with:

```
// client = new CouchbaseClient();
List<Entity> e = new List<Entity> { new Entity { Title = "Entity1" } };
client.Store(StoreMode.Set, "EntityItem", e);
List<Entity> output = client.Get<List<Entity>>("EntityItem"); // return 1 item
```

but, when I refactor the same code nothing seems to be stored:

```
// assembly called Entity.Core

// 1. Entity

[Serializable]
[EntityAttribute(Description = "description")]
public class Entity : EntityBase<Entity>
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Entity() { }
}

// 2. EntityBase
public abstract class EntityBase : IEntity<T> where T : new()
{
    private Couchbase _client = new CouchbaseClient("vBucket", "vBucketPassword");
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public static T Instance { get { return Singleton<T>.Instance; } }

    private IEnumerable<T> ToCache<T>() where T : new() { // gets items from my data source }

    public List<T> Get()
    {
        List<T> entity = this._client.Get<List<T>>(this.Name);

        // if not in cache, call ToCache<T>() to get the object, cache it and return

        return entity;
    }
}

// 3. IEntity is the same as above

// 4. Singleton<T> is a class that constructs a singleton pattern based on the T
```

when I test this within a console application, the name gets assigned in cache, but the item is always null, coming back from cache?

```
// client = new CouchbaseClient();
List<Entity> entity = Entity.Instance.Get(); // returns, for example 4 items as expected
client.Store(StoreMode.Set, "EntityItem", entity); // should store List<Entity>[4] in cache
List<Entity> output = client.Get<List<Entity>>("EntityItem"); // returns null
```

I'm assuming it's because I'm trying to define the client and entity within the abstract class from which my entity is defined? Is this type of inference possible?

**Update**
I modified my test to pass the CouchbaseClient instance to the .Get() method. Seems that, having the CouchbaseClient reference within the EntityBase class screwed around. I'm not 100% sold on this approach through.

Comment: Could you confirm that you have the same app.config in both apps?  In the console app, you imply you're calling the parameterless constructor which assumes the "couchbase" section in app|web.config.  The constructor you call in your entity, also needs that section defined.

Comment: hi john, I did confirm and the keys where correct. I ended up created a separate class that defines the CouchbaseClient and passes that to my method. works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the bucket username and password as configuration values to the client on initialize. A blank constructor does not word in my scenario.